# Marketing Cloud - Click Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud

When in Marketing Cloud > My Tracking > Click Activity > Email Overlay View, the majority of clicks on my emails are always on a URL that starts with "http://view.comms.mycompanyname....."

I'm trying to understand what that refers to? There is text on this page that states "The following are URLs that could not be matched by the overlay. These URLs may be from the text version of the email or may have been generated by Dynamic Content or AMPScript." however my email does not use any Dynamic Content.

How can I figure out which URL to attribute these clicks to?

Comment: How are you formatting your links in the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) When you create template based emails, the links such as 'One-click unsubscribe', 'profile center', etc. are included in the footer of the emails. Those are the dynamic content that is being referred to in the message that you see(even if you have not added any dynamic content in your emails).

2) Apart from this, if you have used any ampscript code which displays a particular link as per one condition and another link as per another condition(so on and so forth), in that case, all those links will be displayed below the message area where you are currently viewing the links starting from "views.comms..." while in the 'Job Links' tab, you will see only the link that was picked up during run time as per the condition.

So, to get proper tracking information, check the 'Link View'. However, Email Studio->Tracking is not the best place to get tracking information anymore. You should use 'Analytics Builder' for this.

Comment: Thank you! What is the best report to use to find URL click data in Analytics Builder?

Comment: You can use 'Email Performance Over Time' report type to find URL click data.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any more visual ways to see email heat maps?